# How to deploy the docbook to the Maven site?

Tags: maven, docbook

I'm using [the docbkx-tools](https://code.google.com/p/docbkx-tools/) for creating the DocBook by using Maven. At the moment I can produce the book in various formats. I also achieve to deploy my Maven site to the web server by using the Wagon through the WebDav already.

I would like to publish them together, the generated DocBook and my Maven site, by using the command like `mvn clean install site:deploy`. Could you please help to shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simple need to copy the generated pdf/rtf/html whatever to the correct location and it will be deployed with the maven-site or you can generate directly into the target location for the site like this:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>com.agilejava.docbkx</groupId>
    <artifactId>docbkx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.14</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>docbook</groupId>
        <artifactId>docbook-xml</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate-pdf</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>pre-site</phase>
        <configuration>
          <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/docbkx</sourceDirectory>
          <xincludeSupported>true</xincludeSupported>
          <includes>maui.xml</includes>
          <foCustomization>src/docbkx/fopdf.xsl</foCustomization>
          <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/</targetDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

You shouldn't use site:deploy you should use **mvn site** and **mvn site-deploy** instead to get run the site [life-cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Comment: How to add it to the "project information" as link?

Answer (score 2):

You can control the docbook output directory with this property : [`<targetDirectory>`](http://docbkx-tools.sourceforge.net/docbkx-maven-plugin/generate-pdf-mojo.html#targetDirectory) (default is `${basedir}/target/docbkx/<something dependending on the output format>`.

On the other hand the `maven-site-plugin` will get all files under [`<inputDirectory>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#inputDirectory) the create to site (globally, it make a zip with everything in the directory). Default is `project.reporting.outputDirectory`

So if you change the docbook plugin `<targetDirectory>` to something in `maven-site-plugin <inputDirectory>` : the docbook output will be included in the generated site zip.

Additionally, to be sure that your docbook plugin will be run before the site get deployed, you need to bind the docbook plugin the some phase in the `site lifecycle` before the `site-deploy`. So one of those phase is OK : `pre-site` `site` `post-site` 
Here is more details about [binding a plugin to a phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Configuring_Build_Plugins)